# Why does addClass and removeClass no longer work when slider loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel slider that has 4 circles underneath it to notify the user when a particular slider is being displayed. To do that, I add and remove classes depending on the index.

This code works for me the first time around, but then stops working once the carousel loops again back to index 0. I know that the code is working because all my console logs show up in my console. So the loop is definitely happening. The problem is that my jQuery code stops adding and removing classes once the slider loops.

How can I make the addClass and removeClass methods in jQuery keep working once the slider loops back to index 0?

```
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="greenCircle carouselCircle"></div>
      <div class="greyCircle2 greenCircle2 carouselCircle"></div>
      <div class="greyCircle3 greenCircle3 carouselCircle"></div>
      <div class="greyCircle4 greenCircle4 carouselCircle"></div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function() {

if (index === 0){
  $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greenCircle4");
  $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle4");
     console.log("ahoy I am index 0");


}

  else if(index === 1){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greenCircle");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle");
     $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle2");
      console.log("ahoy I am index 1");
    }

    else if(index === 2){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle3");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle2");
       console.log("ahoy I am index 2");

    }

     else if(index === 3){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle4");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle3");
     $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle");
     $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greenCircle");
     console.log("Ahoy I am index 3");
    }

});
```

The following is the loop code, where I injected my jQuery into. It is a bit long so this is only if you have to know all the particulars.

```
    /**
    * Wallop.js
    *
    * @fileoverview Minimal JS library to show & hide things
    *
    * @author Pedro Duarte
    * @author http://pedroduarte.me/wallop
    *
    */
    (function(global){
      function Wallop(selector, options) {
        if (!selector) { throw new Error('Missing selector. Refer to Usage documentation: https://github.com/peduarte/wallop#javascript'); }

        for (var i = 0; i < selectorPool.length; i++) {
          if (selectorPool[i] === selector) {
            throw new Error('An instance of Wallop with this selector already exists.');
          }
        }

        this.options = {
          buttonPreviousClass: 'Wallop-buttonPrevious',
          buttonNextClass: 'Wallop-buttonNext',
          itemClass: 'Wallop-item',
          currentItemClass: 'Wallop-item--current',
          showPreviousClass: 'Wallop-item--showPrevious',
          showNextClass: 'Wallop-item--showNext',
          hidePreviousClass: 'Wallop-item--hidePrevious',
          hideNextClass: 'Wallop-item--hideNext',
          carousel: true
        };

        // Whitelist elements which contain `length`
        this.whitelist = {
          'form': true
        };

        if (selector.length > 0 && !this.whitelist[selector]) {
          throw new Error('Selector cannot be an array, Refer to Usage documentation: https://github.com/peduarte/wallop#javascript');
        } else {
          this.$selector = selector;
        }

        this.options = extend(this.options, options);
        this.event = null;

        // "Global vars"
        this.reset();
        this.buttonPrevious = this.$selector.querySelector(' .' + this.options.buttonPreviousClass);
        this.buttonNext = this.$selector.querySelector(' .' + this.options.buttonNextClass);

        this.bindEvents();
        this.createCustomEvent();

        // If there is no active item, start at 0
        if (this.currentItemIndex === -1) {
          this.currentItemIndex = 0;
          addClass(this.allItemsArray[this.currentItemIndex], this.options.currentItemClass);
        }



        // Update button states to make sure the correct state is set on initialization
        this.updateButtonStates();

        // Wrapped in timeout function so event can
        // be listened from outside at anytime
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.event.detail.currentItemIndex = _this.currentItemIndex;
          _this.$selector.dispatchEvent(_this.event);
        }, 0);
      }

      var selectorPool = [];

      var WS = Wallop.prototype;

      // Update prev/next disabled attribute
      WS.updateButtonStates = function () {
        if ((!this.buttonPrevious && !this.buttonNext) || this.options.carousel) { return; }

        if (this.currentItemIndex === this.lastItemIndex) {
          this.buttonNext.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else if (this.currentItemIndex === 0) {
          this.buttonPrevious.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
      };

      // Reset all settings by removing classes and attributes added by goTo() & updateButtonStates()
      WS.removeAllHelperSettings = function () {
        removeClass(this.allItemsArray[this.currentItemIndex], this.options.currentItemClass);
        removeClass($$(this.options.hidePreviousClass, this.$selector), this.options.hidePreviousClass);
        removeClass($$(this.options.hideNextClass, this.$selector), this.options.hideNextClass);
        removeClass($$(this.options.showPreviousClass, this.$selector), this.options.showPreviousClass);
        removeClass($$(this.options.showNextClass, this.$selector), this.options.showNextClass);

        if (!this.buttonPrevious && !this.buttonNext) { return; }

        this.buttonPrevious.removeAttribute('disabled');
        this.buttonNext.removeAttribute('disabled');
      };

      // Method to add classes to the right elements depending on the index passed
      WS.goTo = function (index) {
        if (index === this.currentItemIndex) { return; }

        // Fix the index if it's out of bounds and carousel is enabled
        index = index === -1 && this.options.carousel ? this.lastItemIndex : index;
        index = index === this.lastItemIndex + 1 && this.options.carousel ? 0 : index;

        // Exit when index is out of bounds
        if (index < 0 || index > this.lastItemIndex) { return; }

        this.removeAllHelperSettings();

        var isForwards = (index > this.currentItemIndex || index === 0 && this.currentItemIndex === this.lastItemIndex) && !(index === this.lastItemIndex && this.currentItemIndex === 0);
        addClass(this.allItemsArray[this.currentItemIndex], isForwards ? this.options.hidePreviousClass : this.options.hideNextClass);
        addClass(this.allItemsArray[index], this.options.currentItemClass + ' ' + (isForwards ? this.options.showNextClass : this.options.showPreviousClass));

        this.currentItemIndex = index;

$(document).ready(function() {

if (index === 0){
  $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greenCircle4");
  $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle4");
     console.log("ahoy I am index 0");


}

  else if(index === 1){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greenCircle");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle");
     $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle2");
      console.log("ahoy I am index 1");
    }

    else if(index === 2){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle3");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle2");
       console.log("ahoy I am index 2");

    }

     else if(index === 3){
    $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle4");
    $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greyCircle3");
     $(".carouselCircle").removeClass("greyCircle");
     $(".carouselCircle").addClass("greenCircle");
     console.log("Ahoy I am index 3");
    }

});



    /*







        this.updateButtonStates();

        this.event.detail.currentItemIndex = this.currentItemIndex;
        this.$selector.dispatchEvent(this.event);
      };

      // Previous item handler
      WS.previous = function () {
        this.goTo(this.currentItemIndex - 1);
      };

      // Next item handler
      WS.next = function () {
        this.goTo(this.currentItemIndex + 1);
      };

      // Update global variables
      WS.reset = function () {
        this.allItemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.$selector.querySelectorAll(' .' + this.options.itemClass));
        this.currentItemIndex = this.allItemsArray.indexOf(this.$selector.querySelector(' .' + this.options.currentItemClass));
        this.lastItemIndex = this.allItemsArray.length - 1;
      };

      // Attach click handlers
      WS.bindEvents = function () {
        selectorPool.push(this.$selector);

        var _this = this;

        if (this.buttonPrevious) {
          this.buttonPrevious.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            _this.previous();
          });
        }

        if (this.buttonNext) {
          this.buttonNext.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            _this.next();
          });
        }

      };

      // Method to bind custom event
      WS.on = function (eventName, callback) {
        this.$selector.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
      };

      // Method to unbind custom event
      WS.off = function (eventName, callback) {
        this.$selector.removeEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
      };

      // Create custom Event
      WS.createCustomEvent = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.event = new CustomEvent('change', {
          detail: {
            wallopEl: _this.$selector,
            currentItemIndex: Number(_this.currentItemIndex)
          },
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        });
      };

      // Helper functions
      function $$(element, container) {
        if (!element) { return; }
        if (!container) {
          container = document;
        }
        return container.querySelector('.' + element);
      }

      function addClass(element, className) {
        if (!element) { return; }
        element.className = (element.className + ' ' + className).trim();
      }

      function removeClass(element, className) {
        if (!element) { return; }
        element.className = element.className.replace(className, '').trim();
      }

      function extend(origOptions, userOptions){
        var extendOptions = {}, attrname;
        for (attrname in origOptions) { extendOptions[attrname] = origOptions[attrname]; }
        for (attrname in userOptions) { extendOptions[attrname] = userOptions[attrname]; }
        return extendOptions;
      }

      // Pollyfill for CustomEvent() Constructor - thanks to Internet Explorer
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Polyfill
      function CustomEvent(event, params) {
        params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
        var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        evt.initCustomEvent(event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail);
        return evt;
      }

      CustomEvent.prototype = window.CustomEvent ? window.CustomEvent.prototype : {};
      window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;

      // Exports to multiple environments
      if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){ //AMD
        define(function () { return Wallop; });
      } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports){ //node
        module.exports = Wallop;
      } else { // browser
        // use string because of Google closure compiler ADVANCED_MODE
        /* jslint sub:true */
        global['Wallop'] = Wallop;
      }
    }(this));
```

Comment: Can we see the 'loop' code?

Comment: what does index hold before or during execution?Need to index value,may be its undefined and hence none of the conditions are met and failing your expectations.

Comment: index holds this.currentIndex.

Comment: I added all of the loop code in case anyone needs to know the particulars. Index is looping without a problem, as I keep getting a console.log in my console indicating the exact index.

Comment: This code is really bad.  Can I help get you started a bit?  http://jsfiddle.net/99ftLpy5/  Any time you notice yourself starting to write an `if` statement with a lot of repeated code, reconsider what you're doing.  There's likely a better way.  In the code I just posted, we simply select the "nth" circle to mark it as active or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are **incrementing** the ***`index`*** variable after a specific time using **`setInterval(callback, intervalPeriod)`**.

The problem here is You are using the **jQuery** selector **`$(".carousalCircle")`** to select the Elements which ***selects all the circles***. So, select the *appropriate circles* and then add/remove Class.

Hope this hints you understood the problem.